# Azure Devops task versions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been setting up a build pipeline which included a Nuget Restore task.

I followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/packages/nuget-restore?view=azure-devops but the pipeline stalled for long enough for me to cancel it.

Looking at a build pipeline already in place for another project, I noticed version 0 of the Nuget Restore task was being used whereas the one I was trying to figure was version 2.

Having altered my build pipeline to use version 0 of the task, the build pipeline now completes in a reasonable time.

The main question I have regards the fact that I struggle find documentation on the Devops build tasks and when I do there is little explanation of what all the fields and options are used for when to use the different versions.

Can anyone recommend a resource for that?

Failing that can anyone offer an insight as to what is the difference between each version of the Nuget Restore task and when to use each?

Thanks

Comment: Best way to find what you want is perhaps asking your question in the repository: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/main/docs/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli.md

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think the 'version' means this, right?

[image]

If so, when you change the command from 2 to 0, the task already changed in fact.

You can see the task name here:

[image]

**2.*:**

NuGetCommand@2

Details link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops

**0.*:**

NuGetInstaller@0

Details link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/prev-versions/nuget-installer-0?view=tfs-2017

For the index of most DevOps built-in tasks:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops

For those backward compatible tasks：

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=tfs-2017

The above resources should be enough.